# 403 connecting to IoT websocket using signed url

Tags: websocket, amazon-iam, paho, aws-iot

I've been trying to connect to IoT MQTT in a web browser, so I'm generating a signed URL and connecting with Paho. However, even though I'm generating the signed URL using an IAM role that has the AWSIoTFullAccess policy attached to it (and thus should have access to all IoT operations on all resources!), I get a 403 error whenever I connect (using Paho or wscat). Here is the code I'm using to generate the signed URL:

```
@APP.route(VERSION_PREFIX + 'signedurl', methods=['GET'])
def get_signed_url():
  session = STS.assume_role(RoleArn=IAM_ROLE_ARN,
        RoleSessionName=str(uuid.uuid4()))['Credentials']
  endpt = os.getenv('REALTIME_WSS_ENDPT')

  t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
  datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

  method = 'GET'
  protocol = 'wss'
  uri = '/mqtt'
  service = 'iotdevicegateway'
  algorithm = 'AWS-HMAC-SHA256'

  credential_scope = f"{datestamp}/us-west-2/{service}/aws4_request"
  canonical_query = "X-Amz-Algorithm=" + algorithm
  canonical_query += "&X-Amz-Credential=" + urllib.parse.quote_plus(session['AccessKeyId'] + '/' + credential_scope, safe='')
  canonical_query += "&X-Amz-Date=" + amzdate
  canonical_query += "&X-Amz-Expires=86400"
  canonical_query += "&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"

  canonical_headers = "host:" + endpt
  payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
  canonical_request = f"{method}\n{uri}\n{canonical_query}\n{canonical_headers}\nhost\n{payload_hash}"

  string_to_sign = f"{algorithm}\n{amzdate}\n{credential_scope}\n{hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()}"
  signing_key = get_signature_key(session['SecretAccessKey'], datestamp, 'us-west-2', service)
  signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

  canonical_query += "&X-Amz-Signature=" + signature
  canonical_query += "&X-Amz-Security-Token=" + urllib.parse.quote_plus(session['SessionToken'], safe='')
  return make_response(f"{protocol}://{endpt}{uri}?{canonical_query}")
```

I've followed the example of MQTT over WSS as exactly as possible, and my assumed role has all IoT permissions. What am I doing wrong here?